# Fastest rails query for any N records with criteria

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to find N records that begin with a string that is provided

e.g.

```
Book.where("isbn like ?", "#{partial}%").take(5)
```

or

```
Book.where("isbn like ?", "#{partial}%").limit(5)
```

These both work but I am wondering if they are the absolute most performant things I can be doing. I am getting greedy, as they both seem fine but I want to know what the fastest possible way to grab five records would be in this situation. I don't care about order or anything. Just any five that have "isbn like partial"